# Login not found cakephp 2.10

Tags: cakephp

Estoy haciendo una migración de una app que funciona correctamente a un servidor nuevo, esta app está en *cakephp 2.10*.

Lo he instalado todo en el servidor y el certificado *ssl* también, pero no me arranca la aplicación: entra en el **`index.php`** que hay en la raíz del proyecto, y lo manda al **`index.php`** que hay en webroot, pero de aquí debería saltar al login que hay en **`Controller/UsersController.php`**, pero me sale el error:

> Not found Server at myurl Port 443

He probado todo lo que me han dicho:

- Activar mod_rewrite
- Poner:

  ```
  Router::connect('/login/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
  Router::connect('/login_mantenimiento/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login_mantenimiento'));
  Router::connect('/logout/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'));
  ```
- Tocar los **`*.htaccess`**

Mi *htaccess* de la raíz tiene el siguiente contenido:

```
.<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    # Uncomment if you have a .well-known directory in the root folder, e.g. for the Let's Encrypt challenge
    # https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5785
    #RewriteRule ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>

#Para los ficheros excel
php_value max_execution_time 10000
php_value memory_limit 768M
Options -Indexes
#Gzip
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x- javascript application/javascript application/json
</ifmodule>
#End Gzip
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 5 days"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 5 days"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 5 days"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 5 days"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 5 days"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 5 days"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 5 days"
</ifModule>
FileETag none
```

Y mi *htaccess* de *webroot* tiene el siguiente código:

```
# Uncomment the following to prevent the httpoxy vulnerability
# See: https://httpoxy.org/
#<IfModule mod_headers.c>
#   RequestHeader unset Proxy
#</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /path/to/cake/app
    #RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```